# scala playframework how to assign new Values to a Model

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I hava little complex Model in a scala playframework project. I have to do some database requests and then I have to assign new Values to a Model.

The whole method looks like this:

```
def getEditProcessTemplateData(processTemplateId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    //Get all steps of this process templates
    val stepIds: Future[Seq[Int]] = processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplateIds(processTemplateId)

    val process = for {
      allApprovedProcessTemplates <- processTemplateDTO.getApprovedProcessTemplates //Get all approved process templates
      processTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplateId) // Get the Process Template
      prerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      postConditions <- getProcessTemplateForEdit(processPostConditionsDTO.getProcessPostConditionProcessTemplateIdsByProcessTemplateId(processTemplateId))
      approvedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.approveprocess)
      trainedProcessTemplate <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessTemplate(processTemplate.get.trainingsprocess)
      processSteps <- processTemplateDTO.getProcessStepTemplates(processTemplateId)
      // Step prerequisites
      processStepsPrerequisites <- getProcessStepsPrerequisites(stepIds)
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites <- getProcessTemplateForStepPrerequisite(stepIds)
      // Step post conditions
      processStepsPostConditions <- getProcessStepsPostConditions(stepIds)
      processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate <- getProcessStepPostConditionProcessTemplate(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepPostConditions <- getProcessTemplateForStepPostCondition(stepIds)
      // Derived processes
      derivedProcesses <- getDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses <- getProcessStepsDerivedProcesses(stepIds)
      // Process to process step
      processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates <- getProcessStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates(stepIds)
      processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep <- getProcessTemplateToProcessStepId(stepIds)
      responsible <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all responsibles for this process template
      accountable <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getAccountableProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all accountables for this process template
      consulted <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getConsultedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
      informed <- raciProcessTemplateDTO.getInformedProcessTemplates(processTemplateId) // get all consulted for this process template
    } yield (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
      processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
      processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed)

    process.map({ case (allApprovedProcessTemplates, processTemplate, prerequisites, postConditions, processSteps, processStepsPrerequisites,
    processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites, processStepsPostConditions, processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate, processTemplatesForStepPostConditions, derivedProcesses,
    processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses, processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates, processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep, approvedProcessTemplate, trainedProcessTemplate, responsible, accountable, consulted, informed) =>

      processSteps.map{ psteps: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] =>
        Future.sequence(psteps.map {
          step => {
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get)
            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqs => step.copy(prerequisites = Some(prereqs)))
          }
        })
      }

      Ok(Json.obj(
        "allApprovedProcessTemplates" -> allApprovedProcessTemplates,
        "processTemplate" -> processTemplate,
        "prerequisites" -> prerequisites,
        "postConditions" -> postConditions,
        "approvedProcessTemplate" -> approvedProcessTemplate,
        "trainedProcessTemplate" -> trainedProcessTemplate,
        //       Step prerequisites
        "processStepsPrerequisites" -> processStepsPrerequisites,
        "processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate" -> processStepsPrerequisiteProcessTemplate,
        "processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites" -> processTemplatesForStepPrerequisites,
        // Step post conditions
        "processStepsPostConditions" -> processStepsPostConditions,
        "processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate" -> processStepPostConditionProcessTemplate,
        "processTemplatesForStepPostConditions" -> processTemplatesForStepPostConditions,
        // Derived processes
        "derivedProcesses" -> derivedProcesses,
        "processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses" -> processTemplatesForStepDerivedProcesses,
        // Process to process step
        "processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates" -> processStepsTemplates_ProcessTemplates,
        "processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep" -> processTemplatesForProcessTemplatesToProcessStep,
        "steps" -> processSteps,
        "responsible" -> responsible,
        "accountable" -> accountable,
        "consulted" -> consulted,
        "informed" -> informed
      ))
    })
  }
```

The part of the code where I have problems is this:

```
  processSteps.map{ psteps: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] =>
    Future.sequence(psteps.map {
      step => {
        val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get)
        prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqs => step.copy(prerequisites = Some(prereqs)))
      }
    })
  }
```

I got this error:

```
found   : Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel] => scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]

required: models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel => ?
[error]       processSteps.map{ psteps: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] =>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that `processSteps` is a `Future[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]`? It seems to be just a `Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]` or `Future[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]`.

Comment: do you mean my comment? that could be wrong you're right.

Comment: That's basically what the error message says;)

Comment: do you have an Idea how to solve this?

Comment: It depends what is the real type of `processSteps`. Can you check it?

Comment: processSteps is a Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] .. `val s: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] = processSteps` is compiled perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have already in place code that you need, you just need a small modification:

```
Future.sequence {
    processSteps.map { step =>
        val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteIdsByProcessTemplateIdSeq(step.id.get)
        prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqs => step.copy(prerequisites = Some(prereqs)))
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good, but does not really work ... I return all the stuff with the `Ok(..)` back to frontend. but the prerequisites in the steps are empty

Comment: When I try to print them right after adding like this: 

`processSteps.map { step => {  println("ßßßßßßß", step.prerequisites) }}`

its empty

Comment: @Felix Aren't the `step.prerequisites` populated only when the `prerequisiteFuture` finishes? You should println `step` after `step.copy(prerequisites = Some(prereqs))`.

Comment: And also when I print it right after the copy. I got an Empty list. so the assigning does not work

Comment: this works inside: `step.prerequisites = Some(prereqs)`

Comment: but how can I assign it to the Ok()

Comment: Try `Action.async{  val resFuture = Future.sequence{ ...//whatever you do here} resFuture.map{ res => Ok(res) } }`